No wifi adapter found on ubuntu 20.04
I just installed ubuntu 20.04 LTS on my msi katana 15 b13vfk, but i cant connect to wifi. I tried many ways to install it, but nothing worked. Disabled secure boot, bcs sometimes that can make troubles, but again nothing. Here is the output from the command lshw -C network:
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:620-61f memory:6203134000-6203137fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       logical name: enp5s0
       version: 15
       serial: 04:7c:16:3a:9d:95
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.15.0-107-generic duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=192.168.8.108 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:17 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:76204000-76204fff memory:76200000-76203fff

I tried some things, but my wifi adapter still not found

Welcome to AskUbuntu! What does the output of uname -r say? Also, what have you tried?

Output: 5.15.0-107-generic. I tried with sudo apt install backport-iwlwifi-dkms and clonning different wifi drivers from github and installing them.

This post says to try the dkms package for Ubuntu Jammy: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/b/backport-iwlwifi-dkms/backport-iwlwifi-dkms_9858-0ubuntu3.3_all.deb You can install the deb file by using cd to change to the directory that contains the downloaded deb file and then run sudo apt update and sudo apt install ./backport-iwlwifi-dkms_9858-0ubuntu3.3_all.deb

sorry, I just edited my last comment to include a hyperlink to the referenced post so if it doesn't show at "This post" at the beginning of my comment, then refresh this page to update the comments here.

It worked ^^ Tnx a lot, u saved my day.
